# mysql in docker only works when changing folder name

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I was working on a project that uses docker-compose to bring up a container with a REST API  (python) and another with a mysql db. The API exposes an endpoint that calls the db (sqlalchemy). At some point, I started getting this error when calling the API:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (pymysql.err.OperationalError) (1130, "192.168.80.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server")
(Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
```

Then, I cloned a [similar project](https://github.com/hogeline/sample_fastapi) that uses the same libraries for everything and it worked. After this, I spent the next 6 hours in a [ship-of-theseus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ship_of_Theseus)-like effort turning the working project into my own project, and it still worked. What I found out in the end is if I change the folder name of my existing, non-functional project, it will start functioning.

Additional information:

- Every time I ran docker, I made sure to remove everything by running it in this fashion:

```
docker system prune -a && docker-compose up --build --force-recreate
```

- When copying my broken project into a new location, it was still broken
- When copying my broken project into a new location, but changing its folder name afterwards, it would work

My question is - is there any form of caching that I don't know about that maybe gets invalidated when I change the folder name? Or is there another problem that I'm overlooking?

Comment: The current directory name is used as the default [Compose project name](https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/envvars/#compose_project_name) which affects the generated names of various things.  Do you have a [mcve] that could demonstrate the problem, and a specific directory name that doesn't work?

Comment: Great, I think that might be the problem. When I `up` the broken project with `-p foo`, it works. Unfortunately I can't provide a minimum working example as I don't know how I broke it in the first place, and if I try to build it from scratch now, it will just work out of the box. Seems like docker is still saving something that I broke at some point along with the project name, since my original project name doesn't work but any other one will. I would just be interested in what kind of resource that would be, as I delete all images, networks etc. before every run.

Comment: Named volumes too?  Compose will often try to preserve those, and that could lead you to a broken database.

Comment: Good point! I can't reproduce it anymore, but I'll keep an eye open for this in the future. I did have a named volume, and maybe I broke it at one point and then it was still coupled to the directory name even when I fixed it